# tkinter simple dialog - why does cancel get called?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to understand why when I click the 'ok' button that the cancel button is also called. I can't find a way to tell if cancel is called by itself or with the ok button. The event always seems to be None when the functions are called so how can you tell them apart?

I've a couple of other posts similar to this, but in that case it seemed like the event was different.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.simpledialog

class Ask(tk.simpledialog.Dialog):
    def ok(self, event=None):
        print('dbg ok', event)
        return super().ok(self)

    def cancel(self, event=None):
        print('dbg cancel', event)
        return super().cancel(self)

def show_dialog(app):
    dialog = Ask(title="ask", parent=app)

def main():
    app = tk.Tk()

    app.title('Dialog')

    string_button = ttk.Button(app, text='Show', width=25, command=lambda : show_dialog(app))
    string_button.pack()

    exit_button = ttk.Button(app, text='Close', width=25, command=app.destroy)
    exit_button.pack()

    app.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `tkinter`'s source code (in `tkinter/simpledialog.py`):

```py
class Dialog(Toplevel):
    ...
    def ok(self, event=None):
        ...
        try:
            self.apply()
        finally:
            self.cancel()
    ...
    def apply(self):
        '''
        This method is called automatically to process the data, *after*
        the dialog is destroyed. By default, it does nothing.
        '''
        pass # override
```

So when you call `super().ok(self)` (which should actually be `super().ok()`), it calls `self.cancel` which you also defined. But you can just use a variable to determine if the `ok`/`apply` was called:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.simpledialog

class Ask(tk.simpledialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.oked = False
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def apply(self):
        self.oked = True
        print(f"[Debug]: Ok")

    def cancel(self, event=None):
        if not self.oked:
            print(f"[Debug]: Cancel {event=}")
        return super().cancel(self)

def show_dialog(app):
    dialog = Ask(title="ask", parent=app)

def main():
    app = tk.Tk()

    app.title("Dialog")

    string_button = ttk.Button(app, text="Show", width=25, command=lambda : show_dialog(app))
    string_button.pack()

    exit_button = ttk.Button(app, text="Close", width=25, command=app.destroy)
    exit_button.pack()

    app.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: any idea on why the ok code would call the cancel code? seems a bit odd. seems like they should have added a clean up function instead.

Comment: @kdubs I agree that it's not well designed but I am pretty sure their reasoning was that no one was supposed to override those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tk.simpledialog.Dialog.ok` is what calls its cancel method. You directly ran these functions in your code, so of course this will happen.

Comment: ok, that seems a little odd.   was finding it useful to use the super().ok so I didn't have to write that code (in my  real program). I guess I'll have to mimic what ok does

Comment: @kdubs Really, it isn't. It even makes sense. Exiting the window can mean both "okay, I understand" or "just go away". If you don't like it, you can check out the source code for `tkinter.simpledialog` and see what changes you can make.